# Display slide number in reveal.js printout

Tags: pdf, printing, reveal.js

I have activated slideNumber for my reveal.js based slides and they show up nicely on the HTML view.

Now I would like to also show them on the PDF printout that I generate with Chrome as suggested on the documentation.

It seems that its all one large page so even header and footer display only once for all slides rather than on each slide. Is there a way to print reveal.js slides that works nicely for these sort of things?

Answer (score 2):

If you are printing HTML files which are heavily relying on CSS, the general guideline to create an *'elegant'* print representation of the same HTML, is to create an appropriate CSS for *print*.

In RevealJS the PDF generation is controlled by the *css/print/pdf.css* file. So my advice is this:

1. Go and locate the file *pdf.css* on your system.
2. Open it in a text editor of your choice.
3. Locate the string "`slide-number`" inside the file.
4. Determine the context this string appears in: Is it commented out? Is it set to use `display: none` or similar?
5. Change the setting for `slide-number` accordingly.

---

### Update

Inside the *pdf.css*, there is the following section right after line 32:

```
/* SECTION 2: Remove any elements not needed in print.
   This would include navigation, ads, sidebars, etc. */
.nestedarrow,
.reveal .controls,
.reveal .progress,
.reveal .slide-number,
.reveal .playback,
.reveal.overview,
.fork-reveal,
.share-reveal,
.state-background {
        display: none !important;
}
```

Change this to:

```
/* SECTION 2: Remove any elements not needed in print.
   This would include navigation, ads, sidebars, etc. */
.nestedarrow,
.reveal .controls,
.reveal .progress,
.reveal .playback,
.reveal.overview,
.fork-reveal,
.share-reveal,
.state-background {
        display: none !important;
}
```

Voila!

---

### Update 2

Meanwhile I cloned the latest sources from GitHub and tested myself...

It seems to me that there is a bug with Reveal.js' PDF generation involved. I've filed a **[bug report](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/issues/1072)** about it on GitHub.

My *'js/reveal.js'* currently has the following setting:

`// Display the page number of the current slide
       //slideNumber: false,
       slideNumber: true,`

So slide numbers ***DO*** appear in the slide deck. Here is a screenshot montage showing this (skipping the title slide). The slide numbers are rather small, but they do show up:

[image: revealjs-slides-html]

My *'css/print/pdf.css'* file has the following setting:

`/* SECTION 2: Remove any elements not needed in print.
   This would include navigation, ads, sidebars, etc. */
.nestedarrow,
.reveal .controls,
.reveal .progress,
//.reveal .slide-number,
.reveal .playback,
.reveal .overview,
.fork-reveal,
.share-reveal,
.state-background {
   display: none !important;
}`

I commented out the line which marks the `.slide-number` as an element that shouldn't be printed.

However, when creating a PDF (using Chrome 39.0.2171.71 (64-bit) on Mac OSX Mavericks 10.9.5), a slide number does only appear for the first slide, not for the following slides. Here is a screenshot montage of the PDF pages (skipping the second slide):

[image: pdfstylesheet-kungfooforreveal js co---outcome]

The title slide shows navigation controls as well as slide number '0' (very small though, but it is there...). The other slides do show neither navigation controls, nor slide numbers.

---

My reveal.js is pulled directly from the current GitHub sources (AFAICS it is the very current one); my remote branch when pulling seems to be `origin/dev`.

Comment: This looks promising. Let me test this later today.

Comment: @ManfredMoser: So? Did you test it?

Comment: That doesnt work since the print view of reveal is essentially one page. So the header and footer and slide number only shows ones for the whole thing. I dug in more and found that there is a fork that repeats the header and I might be able to hack the slide number in a similar manner.

Comment: @ManfredMoser: Häh? The print-to-PDF does produce 1 page per slide. It is almost impossible to "print" any HTML-based content (which goes beyond a certain lenght) to one page only. Don't let yourself be fooled by a print *preview* of the browser. Who knows what CSS that print *preview* uses...

Answer (score 1):

well, one ugly hack will be to:
1. take sequential screenshots.
2. embed each shot in a pdf file.
(or 3. embed it in a ppt and convert ppt into pdf)

Other than that, I couldn't find anything that'd convert it to a good-looking pdf with ease.

---

## An Elegent Hack

Although I still couldn't find a precise solution, I do have, as the title suggests, an elegent hack.

A firefox plugin named [Grab Them All](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/grab-them-all/).

It's basically a script that accesses links in a predefined list and takes screenshots and saves them. But as it's a only a hack, there's some (a lot) of manual work to do.

Firstly, you need to provide hard links to all the webpages, ie, slides in presentation, in a `.txt` file. I did so in a file called `paths.txt` and these were the contents in my case:

```
file:///C:/absolute_path_to_presentation_folder/presentation.html#/
file:///C:/absolute_path_to_presentation_folder/presentation.html#/1
file:///C:/absolute_path_to_presentation_folder/presentation.html#/2
file:///C:/absolute_path_to_presentation_folder/presentation.html#/2/1
file:///C:/absolute_path_to_presentation_folder/presentation.html#/2/2
```

Second and final step: after iNstalling the addon and restarting firefox, just start the addon. It opens a popup like this:
[image]

Now, it's as simple as 1,2,3. Select the `file with URLs`, select the `destination directory` and reduce the `Max page processing time`.

And Voila! `Let's go`

---

All the slides will be downloaded as png format in sequential order. What's left to do is put them in a ppt or pdf format.

Comment: A similar hack would be to print each slide as a pdf and stitch them together.. but I would really rather not use a hack like that.

Comment: I found that reveal has a built in hack for that, which uses phantomjs .. I will test that.

Comment: Problem with the phantomjs approach is there is still no page numbers as it used the print-pdf stylesheet.

Comment: @ManfredMoser: if you want to convert Reveal.js slide decks into PDF, it is best to use the stylesheet located in *css/print/pdf.css* within your Reveal.js structure. Then proceed according to the documentation: *simply add *`?print-pdf`* to the end of the URI of your slide deck; print.

Comment: @KurtPfeifle ... thats what I am doing. But slide number and headers and footer dont work that way..

Comment: @ManfredMoser: Ok, I'll install Reveal.js on this machine to test it myself later tonight. It used to work, I'm sure. Maybe you found a bug?

Comment: @ManfredMoser: Ok, I've installed the newest Reveal.js from the current Git sources. I can confirm that displaying slide numbers does not work currently, even if you set up the system "according to the books"... :-(   -- I propose to file a bug report with the Reveal.js developer.

Comment: @ManfredMoser: I've filed a **[bug report](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/issues/1072)**. Let's see what the developer will say...

Comment: @KurtPfeifle there are patches that replicated the header .. but I have not seen the slide number working. I am going to hack on it myself if I find time..

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem and I have solved it simply by little bit of dom manipulation:

Basicly my prezentation contains of vertical sections which contains slides. So I can rely on that structure and do it by simple added element

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.slides')
                .children().each(
                function (sectionNumber, section) {

                  $(this).children().each(
                      function (slideNumber) {

                        var elem = $("<span></span>", {
                          class: "angular-cz-slide-number",
                          text: sectionNumber + "-" + (slideNumber)
                        });
                       $(this).append(elem);
                      })
                });
          }
      )

</script>
```

In css It can be done like :

```
.reveal .angular-slide-number {
  z-index: 100;
  font-size: 20pt;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0; }
```

In pdf it looks like it is too close to edge, but when you print it (i print 4x4 layout) it looks just fine.

That is basically all.

I like the solution because you can provide also some advanced logic here. For example in our prezentation we have some slides marked as "not printable" because they are extended by next slide, so they shouldn't increase number.